# Can't recover account because forgot email

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, password

I lost my Game Center account password... Because I changed and don't remember. My Apple ID is going to iCloud. I know my iCloud password but I wasn't there for so long, so i used my same apple id and my password. But there is one problem. I need to recover my account for security and I don't remember my email. I can't answer to questions to,because i forgotten all answers. I know only my b-day answer. Thank u for help...

Comment: We can't help you, only Apple can.

Answer (score 1):

The security questions was the last chance to recover the password by your own. In this case now, you have to contact Apple:

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5699